# How create multiple user control on one page?

Tags: javascript

I have class Player which creates audio player, in static method create of this class i render ui of player an insert to dom using innerHtml, with one instance on page it's works fine, but i want creaete many instances on one page. How can I do it? Maybe we have any pattern to do that?

```
class Player1{
player = new Audio()
timeMouseDown = false
volumeMouseDown = false
isRateListActive = false
isVolumeControlActive = false
btnPlay = document.querySelector('.play')
btnVolume = document.querySelector('.volume')
btnDownload = document.querySelector('.download')
btnUpload = document.querySelector('.upload')
// another elements

constructor(){
  this.player.src = "audio/1.mp3"
  this.player.loop = true
}

initListeners(){
  this.btnPlay.addEventListener('click', this.play.bind(this))
  this.btnVolume.addEventListener('click',this.showVolumeControl.bind(this))
  this.btnDownload.addEventListener('click',this.download.bind(this))
  this.btnUpload.addEventListener('click',this.upload.bind(this))
  //another events

}

static create(root){
  debugger
  this.root = document.querySelector(root);
  this.root.innerHTML = `<div class="player">
  <div class="title" oncopy="return false">Название дорожки</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
    <span class="time past_time">00:00</span>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress_bar" data-progress="6rem">
        <div class="progress_line"></div>
        <div class="progress_control"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="time rest_time">00:00</span>
    <div class="rate_picker">
      <div class="rate_list">
        //some tags
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
}
initPlayer() {
  this.initListeners()
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: i have edited my question, but cant put all code because get warning from site

Comment: I would change the class name from Player1 to Player and call Player.initPlayer() within a for loop.